# Google Polymer: paper-dialog doesn't work with google-map inside

Tags: google-maps, modal-dialog, polymer

```
             <paper-button onclick="map.open()">Central Park</paper-button>
                <paper-dialog id="map" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation" with-backdrop>
                    <div class="dialog-map">
                        <h>sdoihsdf</h>
                        <google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942" fit-to-markers></google-map>
                    </div>
                </paper-dialog>
```

When i include google-map into paper-dialog, second doesn't appear, but when i delete map, all works properly. If write google-map outside of this code, for example after paper-dialog, map and dialog work. Example with map inside dialog on polymer i haven't seen, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the console, you are likely getting a "missing API key" warning. You need to get an API key here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Then provide your API key to your google-map component:

```
<google-map
  api-key="[[yourApiKeyHere]]"
  latitude="37.77493"
  longitude="-122.41942"
  fit-to-markers>
</google-map>
```

You might need to specify exact height/width for your google-map to make sure it's visible in the dialog:

```
google-map {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

I was able to get a local demo working:

```
<dom-module id="map-dialog">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }

      google-map {
        height: 200px;
        width: 300px;
      }
    </style>

    <paper-dialog id="dialog">
      <google-map
        api-key="[[apiKey]]"
        latitude="37.77493"
        longitude="-122.41942"
        fit-to-markers></google-map>
    <paper-dialog>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'map-dialog',

      properties: {
        apiKey: {
          type: String,
          value: function() {
             // Return your API key here!!
          }
        },
      },

      ready() {
        this.$.dialog.open();
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```